# Visual Studio reference x64 GAC

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit

How can one get Visual Studio 2005/2008 to reference assemblies in the 64-bit GAC instead of the 32-bit GAC? We are settin the target platfom to x64 and the compiler is throwing the error of

> Error 2 Warning as Error: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Data.dll' targets a different processor Common
>
> Error 3 Warning as Error: Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll'
>   targets a different processor Common
>
> Error 4 Assembly signing failed; output may not be signed -- The system cannot find the file specified. Common

---

**Update 29 Dec 08**

Been trying out [Aaron Stebner's suggestions](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/11/28/497693.aspx) to place 64-bit assemblies onto an isolated location (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\GAC_64) and creating additional entries in the registry like HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\GAC_64 or HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\GAC_64 but Visual Studio 2005 is still not picking it up....

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would need to do this. .NET code that isn't specifically compiled for 32 bit will run 64 bit if it can. This includes the base framework libraries. In short, there is no reason that I know of to compile your assemblies specifically for 64 bit (other than referencing unmanaged 64 bit dlls, but you're talking about the GAC).

Some more information might help here.

Comment: Yes we are compiling our application to specifically target x64. And because of that the compiler complains System.Data or mscorlib are targetting x86.....

Comment: Have you redone the afflicted references after changing the compile target in project properties?

Comment: "Consider a .NET application that is 100% type safe code. In this scenario it is possible to take your .NET executable that you run on your 32-bit machine and move it to the 64-bit system and have it run successfully. Why does this work? Since the assembly is 100% type safe we know that there are no dependencies on native code or COM objects and that there is no 'unsafe' code which means that the application runs entirely under the control of the CLR." -- MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Have you set x64 platform for all projects in your solution in Configuration Manager ?

Comment: Yes but it does not matter. It is the BCL assemblies that the projects are referencing like System.Data.dll and mscorlib.dll. They are referncing the assemblies in the 32-bit GAC. Would be nice to have the option to reference the 64-bit GAC instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool which is completely free,  that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.